# spkl: can't connect with Dynamics 365 (online) instances

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

Could not able connect Dynamics 365 (online) instances from `deploy-plugins.bat`. I am using spkl version 1.0.178.1. Connection is well tested by XrmTooling to connect.

```
Error Details:
The application terminated with an error.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
'https://disco.https//**********.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc?wsdl&sdkversion=8.2'
```

Comment: Are you sure, you posted the correct url? `https://disco.https//` seems strange

Comment: spkl Task Runner v1.0.178.1     Tasks v1.0.178.1
Enter a CRM server name and port [crm.dynamics.com]: https://n*************t.crm4.
dynamics.com
Is this organization provisioned in Microsoft Office 365 (y/n) [y]: y  & getting error details as The application terminated with an error as above.

Comment: i don't know why its appending https://disco in organisation URL.. Please suggest

Comment: Disco is the CRM discovery server. What is spkl and how are you using it? You need to provide more detail about what you are actually trying.

Comment: This issue is being tracked on [GitHub](https://github.com/scottdurow/SparkleXrm/issues/199)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has removed support for TLS 1.0/1.1 in D365 9.0.

Update to the latest version of spkl (this was fixed in [1.0.198](https://github.com/scottdurow/SparkleXrm/issues/199#issuecomment-363859956))